# How do I create heirarchies in Team Foundation Server 2018?

Tags: .net, tfs

I am installing and setting up TFS 2018 on premises. I want to build out a hierarchy but I don't want to create a team project for every single task. But on the other hand I don't want to create one team project for all of the tasks\projects we get from Jira.

Is there no way to build out a sort of hierarchy? You can't create sub team projects. If I simply put task\project folders under one team project how are the work items kept separated?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Team projects are intended to store a *portfolio of related applications*. You should not be creating team projects for individual tasks, or even for individual applications.

Use [teams, iterations, and area paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops) within a single team project for organization. Iterations define your schedule for work, and area paths allow for organization of work items for filtering and assignment to specific teams.